# CloudFlare R2 with Flutter

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, cloudflare-r2

I want to use **CloudFlre** **R2** as storage for my **Flutter** app.
I have **AccessKey**, **SecertKey** and **r2Token**.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a package or HTTP request to upload a file to an **R2** bucket.

I tried using this [Postman Collection](https://www.postman.com/cloudflare-r2/workspace/cloudflare-r2/collection/20913290-14ddd8d8-3212-490d-8647-88c9dc557659?action=share&creator=20913290), but I don't know how to create the headers in dart code.

Can anyone help me with this?